# Python: Running a function N times in 1 second

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a `python function`, i want to run that function `n times` in `1 second`.

How can I achieve that, Can anyone help me?

my function:

```
def run():
   print("hello")
```

I want to run this function may be `1000` times in 1 second.

**i just gave you small example. But my actual function will send
3 api- requests**

Comment: did you try just doing `for _ in range(1000):   run()`?  If your function is that simple it should take less than 1 second.

Comment: You want to control the timing? Or what exactly is the problem? What will you do if the function is too slow?

Comment: basically, i gave you small example of the function. But my function code will send 3 api- requests

Comment: whether or not something can run `n times` in `1 second` is limited to the specifics of the complexity of your function and the compute capabilities of your computer

Comment: And keep doing that every second? Are you asking how to make the function more efficient so that it can run 1000 times in one second. Or how to limit it to 1000 times per second for a longer period of time? If the latter, should it be bursty, or evenly spaced throughout the second? If it takes longer than a second to do 1000, should the next second be limited to 1000 or should the code try to catch up?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

```
import time

for i in range(1000):
    run()
    time.sleep(0.001)


for i in range(n):
    run()
    time.sleep(1/n)
```